# Importing Entity Database Model from MySQL to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: mysql, database, ado.net-entity-data-model, mysql-connector

Im trying to get Entity Data Model with wizard from remote MySQL server. I'm typing proper connection string, then choose next. I see all tables, i can check them. When wizard finished im getting no entity models and this errors:

```
Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.
Access denied for user 'myserver'@'myIP' (using password: NO)
```

P.S. Server Explorer and database sets working fine, I can write/read table data.

Environment:
 Database:
          Windows 2008 Server R2 (Enterprise)
          MySQL Workbench 5.2
          MySQL Connector Net 6.4.4 
 Client:
          Windows 7 64bit Professional
          Visual Studio 2010 
          MySQL Connector 6.4.4
          .NET Framework 4

My Connection String:

```
metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=myserver;User Id=myID;database=myDatabase;password=myPassword"
```

Comment: The message is saying that the user you are using to connect to the database does not have sufficient permissions...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues. The connection string was good, and I could grab data from my application, server browser, etc. But whenever I tried to update the schema, the Entity framework would ignore the password in the config.

**Workaround** - Temporarily give the anonymous user all the necessary permissions on your mysql instance (in my case, local to my machine, so no security threats) and run the model update from Visual Studio. This way, a password won't be necessary.

Once all the entities are updated, go back and revert the permissions to the way they were.

It's not ideal, and I still don't know what the issue is, but it got me past the problem.